# Populate a new column with the value of another column when the value of a third column

Tags: r, lapply, summarize

First time posting here, and new to R. I hope I do it right.

How can use R to populate a new column with the value (just the value) of another column´s row conditional to the value of a third column´s row.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

```
for(i in 1:length(df$column1){        #runs the following code for each line
  if(df$thirdcolumn[i] > 0){              #if logical TRUE then it runs the next line
    df$newcolumn[i] <- df$anothercolumn[i]    #gives value of another column to a new column
  }
}
```